# Style a button (or menu) in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, web

My goal is to apply styling to an ExtJS button and its menu.

I am having trouble applying styling with a css class even to a button. I have tried the following code:

CSS:

```
.testStyle {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

ExtJS:

```
Ext.onReady(function() { 
Ext.create("Ext.button.Button", {
        text: 'Payment',
        scale: 'large',
        cls: 'testStyle',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        menu: [ { text: 'Visa' },
                { text: 'Mastercard' },
                { text: 'American Express' }
        ]
    })
});
```

but no joy. I have also tried this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() { 
Ext.create("Ext.button.Button", {
        text: 'Payment',
        scale: 'large',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        menu: [ { text: 'Visa', cls: 'testStyle' },
                { text: 'Mastercard', cls: 'testStyle' },
                { text: 'American Express', cls: 'testStyle' }
        ]
    })
});
```

but this didnt work either.
I have tried using the various other class/styling options ExtJS mentions but nothing has worked. I have also tried with and without the !important .
Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there are several options. Quick option is adding style to component. Like this:    https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ti8

```
   style: {
       'background-color': 'green',
       'color': 'white'
   },
```

If you want to add css file, you should define file path in app.json file.

```
"css": [
    {
        "path": "/myStyle.css"
    }
],
```

And suggested option is using sass. Please check this:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/theming.html

Comment: This adds a style to the button but not to the button menu.